# how do I make a counter that records how many people walk past a Kinect and have the skeleton change colour when it detex new movement in processing

Tags: processing, openkinect

I was wondering if someone could help me with this problem?

I am making a program that uses an xbox 360 Kinect (v1) model 1414 for motion tracking. I have managed to make the motion capture track the whole body (20 points) and have it leave a fading trail from the old position to the new position but not the colour changing put, nor the counter.

I have text show the the screen the says "people tracked" but no counter, how do I made a counter to recorded the amount of movement (people tracked) and have the skeleton change colour when I the Kinect detex a new person?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Do you already have a Processing sketch that has the parts that are already working? If so, can you add that code to your question? That would make it a lot more feasible to help.